# Is it compulsory to write queries in room off the main thread in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I want to integrate a Room database into my android application (JAVA).
 I went through many contents available on the internet for the Room database, but none of them cleared my doubts , which are

1. Is it compulsory to write queries off the main thread ?
2. If yes what happens if we write queries on main thread ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Is it compulsory to write queries off the main thread ?

No

You can allow Queries to run on main thread by initializing with `.allowMainThreadQueries()`

```
 Room.databaseBuilder(this, MyRoomDataBase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME).allowMainThreadQueries()
```

> 2. If yes what happens if we write queries on main thread ?

If you have specified `.allowMainThreadQueries()` then it will block the main thread until query is executed, otherwise it throw `IllegalStateException` and your app will crash . Its better not to Query on main thread

Comment: Thanks @Manohar Reddy

Comment: Correct answer to the second question would be "If you have specified `.allowMainThreadQueries()` then it will block the main thread until query is executed, otherwise it throws `IllegalStateException` and your app crashes"

Comment: @musooff thanks edited , you are  always  welcome to edit if think it adds some value to the answer .

Comment: Hi, we're using rooms on a Service in a separate process from the `MainActivity`. The service will continue to run even after the `MainActivity` is closed. I just want to get other people's thoughts if it's a good idea to allow `.allowMainThreadQueries()` on a rooms database in this case? We have allowed it for now. All queries to the Database are via message passing from `Flutter` to `MainActivity` to the backend `Service`. We don't block at `Flutter` side using `async` `MethodChannel`s.

Answer (score 2):

By default,Observable room queries run off the main UI thread. If you want to run them over main thread you need to specify it using below code.

```
Room.databaseBuilder(this, MyRoomDataBase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME).allowMainThreadQueries()
```

IF you are wrapping your return type in LiveData you don't need to set `allowMainThreadQueries()`, Queries run asynchronously on a background thread with LiveData and you can observe on it to receive updates in that data.

You can allow queries on main thread if your database is smaller in size and you are not performing any heavy operations over database otherwise builder might lock the UI for a long period of time.